# Array list prints same data for all elements

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to print a dataset fetched and stored in an object. This object uses an arraylist. While getting the data (right before adding it to the array list), all the records print different but when I get to print them, they are same. I am not able to figure out why.

Here is the code

```
void caseClicked()

{
  //println("Inside case clicked");

  for(int i = 0; i < mapData.size(); i++)
  {
    if (dist(mapData.get(i).pf.x, mapData.get(i).pf.y, gX, gY) < percentY(1))
    {
      clickedCaseId = mapData.get(i).icaseNum;
      clickedStateId = mapData.get(i).stateId;
      glyphPosX = mapData.get(i).pf.x;
      glyphPosY = mapData.get(i).pf.y;
      print("Value of icaseNum selected" + mapData.get(i).icaseNum + "\n");
      break;
    }
    else
      continue;
  }

  try{
          db.getConnection(); 
          if (db.conn.connect())
          {
            String tempQ = "select distinct(svin), vfatcount, saccdate, day " + d_year + " where icasenum = " + clickedCaseId + " and istatenum = " + clickedStateId;
            println(tempQ);
            db.conn.query(tempQ);
            Glyph tg1 = new Glyph();                 
            gl.fnVins.clear();
            while (db.conn.next()) 
            {
              tg1.fVin.VIN = db.conn.getString(1);
              tg1.fVin.fatals = (int)Float.parseFloat(db.conn.getString(2));
              println("Value of VIN is " + tg1.fVin.VIN + "\n");
              println("Value of fatals is " + tg1.fVin.fatals + "\n");

              gl.fnVins.add(tg1.fVin);
              gl.gdate = db.conn.getString(3);
              gl.gday = db.conn.getString(4);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < gl.fnVins.size(); i++)
            println("Value of VIN is " + gl.fnVins.get(i).VIN + "\n");

          }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {      
          System.err.println ("Error:DBHelper.dataPointQuery - " + e.toString());
       //   return null;        
      }          
            db.closeConnection();


}
```

Glyph class is

```
public class Glyph
{
  float caseNum = 0;
  float stateId = 0;
  float time = 0;
  int fatal = 0;
  String gday = "", gdate = "";

  class fnVin
  {
    int fatals = 0;
    String VIN = "";
  }

  fnVin fVin = new fnVin();
  ArrayList<fnVin> fnVins = new ArrayList<fnVin>();

}
```

Please can someone help me figure out what's wrong in this implementation?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you also put sample output

Comment: Here is the sample output(with some added comments)                  Query :select distinct(svin), vfatcount, saccdate, day  from year_2001 where icasenum = 60.0 and istatenum = 27.0
Value of VIN is -1

Value of fatals is -1

Value of VIN is 1HGCB7651NA0

Value of fatals is 0

Value of VIN is 1HGCB7651NA0

Value of VIN is 1HGCB7651NA0. Sorry for the format. It won't let me format the text here.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out, see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is: you did not create new tg1.fVin instance before adding it into gl.fnVins in the while loop.

```
gl.fnVins.add(tg1.fVin);
```

To fix this, you have to create new fnVin instance before adding to array in while loop.

```
while (db.conn.next()) {
    fVin fv = new fVin();
    fv.VIN = db.conn.getString(1);
    fv.fatals = (int)Float.parseFloat(db.conn.getString(2));              

    gl.fnVins.add(fv);
}
```

Comment: that throws an error because tg1 is an object of Glyph class. To your point about the instantiating fVin. Isn't that done as soon as any instance of Glyph is created?

Comment: Error occurred since fVin class is an internal class. To fix this, you may create a fVin class public, or create a method to init the object inside Glyph class.

Comment: tg1.fVin is initialized when Glype object is initialized, but it's only initialized once, that's the problem.

Comment: cool! Problem is resolved but it does leave me with some questions which I will read up and clarify. Thanks a lot for your replies.

Comment: It's great to know that this help you. pls kindly marked answer if your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You keep reusing the same `fnVin` object here (inside your `Glyph` class):

```
Glyph.fnVin fVin = new Glyph.fnVin();
```

What you should do instead is, first, delete that line, then use this changed loop:

```
while (db.conn.next()) 
{
    fnVin fVin = new fnVin();
    fVin.VIN = db.conn.getString(1);
    fVin.fatals = (int)Float.parseFloat(db.conn.getString(2));
    // println("Value of VIN is " + fVin.VIN + "\n");
    // println("Value of fatals is " + fVin.fatals + "\n");

    gl.fnVins.add(fVin);
    gl.gdate = db.conn.getString(3);
    gl.gday = db.conn.getString(4);
}
```

I'm not sure based solely on your code, but you may want to consider moving `gdate` and `gday` to your `fVin` inner class as well. Also, you should make `fVin` into a `public class` so you can make new instances of it in this method.